# Orientation to know the scenarios to choice the best "Host Key Verification Strategy" option

Tags: ssh, security, jenkins

About SSH for a remote and secured connection the approach is create in the client a pair of keys, public and private, do a copy of the public key content in the server within the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and do ssh connection from the client to the server to get the server fingerprint and update the `.ssh/known_hosts` file in the client side. It is clear for me.

Now about Jenkins for the *Controller/Agents* scenario. I have read the following:

- [Configuring the SSH Build Agents plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURE.md)

And exists the *Host Key Verification Strategy* option and we have available the following options:

1. Known hosts file Verification Strategy
2. Manually provided key Verification Strategy
3. Manually trusted key Verification Strategy
4. Non verifying Verification Strategy

Well, for security reasons, the 4th can be ignored. For the three first options, when would be mandatory use one approach over the other? - *for what scenario(s)?* - I am posting this question, because is not clear in the official documentation.

Comment: Really not sure why is closed - the scenarios requested to be shared to us are based on specific scenarios - that's the reason of the question

Comment: Not clear why closed either. But clearly every option further diwn the list is less secure. 1 must have OS access to configure; 2 must have app Administer permission to configure; 3 must be approved be a User with Computer.CONFIGURE permission; 4 is implicit. All depends on how much trust you have in your network (public internet, firewalled shared network to isolated network), what permissions users have, etc. YMMV.

Comment: If already have OS access to save keys, then you can go w/known hosts option, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I created a JIRA issue - https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66601

Comment: I sue the approach #3 - I watched a Youtube tutorial - "just that my main concern is if is wise copy and paste the "private" key - I would suggest refer the absolute path to the private key. It in case if a remote user with his credentials get access to Jenkins via web and arrives to that configuration, he only is able to see the path but not the content."